# Split dataframe to sub dataframes and fill content according to the relevant dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following toy dataframe:

```
x  value      id
A  5           1
B  DE          1
C  False       1
D  yes         1
E  -0.9442     1
A  66          2
D  yes         2
E  -0.9442     2
F  Kuku        2
Z  1           2
```

etc.
for each id, we have some set of attributes.
I want to "slice" them by attributes for each `id` (for example id 1 has A,B,C,D and E attributes and `id` 2 has A,D,E,F and Z attributes.
How can I **create such sub dataframes containing only A,B,C,D and E attributes, A,D,E,F and Z attributes** and so on - like boxes of same attributes where I will **store the request id's with the appropriate attributes**?

What I am trying to do is to split the whole dataframe by id's and then extract the attributes of each. Is there any method to do this in a simpler manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dict of [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) objects of `x` grouped by `id`, as follows:

```
x_df_dict = {a: b for a, b in df.groupby('id')['x']}
```

Then, you can access the sub-dataframes (more accurately sub-Series) of `x` by `id`, as follows:

```
print(x_df_dict[1])

0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
Name: x, dtype: object
```

```
print(x_df_dict[2])

5    A
6    D
7    E
8    F
9    Z
Name: x, dtype: object
```